# Phonegap 3.0 Angular.js unable to use InAppBrowser

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova

I'm working on a project based on PhoneGap 3.0 and Angular.js. I try to use InAppBrowser with the following controller :

```
function AccueilCtrl($scope,$window) {
    $scope.openUrl = function() {
        var ref = $window.open('http://www.google.fr', '_blank', 'location=yes');
    };
}
```

I call this function, in a view, with :

```
<a ng-click="openUrl()">Open Page</a>
```

I followed insctructions, and used the cli version of PhoneGap 3.0 :

```
phonegap local plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser.git

phonegap build ios
```

But when I launch the app, either in simulator, or on a real device, the window does not show nav bars at all, it's just full screen. Replacing "_blank" with "_system" doesn't change anything, Safari does not launch.

Do you think this is a bug in PhoneGap or Angular, or am I missing something? How can I debug or trace to find what's wrong? Thx

Comment: Solved !

Just add this line in top of my index.html :

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>

I did not think that this line was important, it was !
2 days to find...